# Laravel socialite login and register by REST - best flow?

Tags: laravel, rest

I'm doing some Android app that needs API and users.
I'm planning adding login (and register) button via Facebook.

I'm wondering: how should the flow of such an operation look like?

My idea:

1. Request the Facebook token in the app.
2. Send the token to the laravel backend by POST request (is this even secure approach?)
3. Get the Facebook user by Facebook token using socialite
4. Create / auth laravel user using Facebook user.
5. Return laravel's bearer token to the app (do I need passport to get the token  or laravel has something built in?)

Is this the best approach?

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you are looking for how to get started on your app, I suggest you check some forums like laravel and some sample codes. SO is mainly when you get stuck with your codes.

Comment: I'm not starting, just wondering what the best practices are.